# (Hackerrank - Fair Rations) When return a string following error appears(C#). error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type string' to int

Tags: c#, .net, string, int, return

**error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type string' to int**

I'm trying to solve HackerRank's [Fair Rations](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fair-rations/problem). I should return an Integer or string "NO". When I trying to return string "NO" the following error message appears

```
// Solution.cs(49,16): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `int'
```

Following is my code.

```
int temp = 0;
string s = "N0";

for(int i = 0; i < B.Length - 1; i++)
{  
   if(B[i] % 2 == 1)
   {
        B[i] = B[i] + 1;
        B[i + 1] = B[i + 1] + 1;
        temp += 2;
   }
}

for(int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
{
    if(B[i] % 2 == 1)
    {
        temp = 0;
    }
}

if(temp > 0)
{
    return temp;
}
else
{
    return s;
}
```

How I return "NO" ?. When I use `Console.WriteLine()' following error messege appears

```
//Solution.cs(18,16): error CS0161: `Solution.fairRations(int[])': not all code paths return a value
```

Comment: How is your method declared? Is it e.g. `int MethodName(...)`? In that case you can't return a string.

Comment: Strings must be **Parsed** into int. There is no automatic conversion. However teh only candidate for this Compilker error is the return, asuming the function said it will return int.

Comment: You can use `string` as return type and return the number as string (`return temp.ToString()`). Just don't perform any calculations using that returned value

Comment: The challenge calls for the output to be written to the output.  So just `Console.WriteLine("NO");` or `Console.WriteLine(temp);` rather than returning it.

Comment: @Wyck When I use `Console.WriteLine()` following error messege appears

`//Solution.cs(18,16): error CS0161: Solution.fairRations(int[]): not all code paths return a value`

Comment: I see now that the C# template uses a TextWriter, not Console output. I've written [a full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61765857/1563833).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand **why** you got confused.  If you go to the site, and choose to write an answer in C#, this is the template you get:

```cs
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Solution {

    // Complete the fairRations function below.
    static int fairRations(int[] B) {


    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        int N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] B = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), BTemp => Convert.ToInt32(BTemp))
        ;
        int result = fairRations(B);

        textWriter.WriteLine(result);

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

But one of the requirements states:

> If it's not possible to do this, print `NO`.

And the instructions say:

> `// Complete the fairRations function below.`

That's a ***lousy template*** for a function that needs to also handle an additional condition of printing `NO` if the solution is not possible.

You'll have to ***modify the signature*** of the `fairRations` function to handle the case where the solution is not possible.  You're also allowed to modify the code in `Main`, which is clearly inadequate for fulfilling the requirements of the challenge as is.

And if you need to write something other than the `int result` to the output, then you'll need to make a different `textWriter.WriteLine` call that outputs a string.

I strongly recommend the pattern used in functions like `int.TryParse` or `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue`.  That pattern is based on these two principles:

1. return a bool to indicate success/fail.
2. deliver the payload for the successful case (in this case: an integer) by means of an out parameter.

Modify the `fairRations` function like so:

```cs
static bool fairRations(int[] B, out int result) {

   if (/* TODO: it is possible? */) {
      result = /* TODO: whatever the result is */;
      return true;
   } else {
      result = 0;
      return false;
   }
}
```

And you may want to modify the call in `Main` as follows:

change...

```cs
        int result = fairRations(B);

        textWriter.WriteLine(result);
```

to...

```cs
        if (fairRations(B, out int result)) {
            textWriter.WriteLine(result);
        } else {
            textWriter.WriteLine("NO");
        }
```

Comment: Or `int? fairRations(int[] B)`, `textWriter.WriteLine(result?.ToString() ?? "NO");`

Comment: @Wyck Thanks for your help!. If you can(only if you can), can you give a example for using `int.TryParse` and `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.TryGetValue ` related to my quection.

Comment: @DulmikaSapumal, I already **did** give an example.  The pattern that `int.TryParse` uses embraces two principles:  1) return a *bool* to indicate success/fail.  2) deliver the payload for the successful case (in this case: an integer) by means of an *out* parameter.  My refactoring of `fairRations` now looks like `bool fairRations(int[] B, out int result)` thanks to me following the pattern.  (I edited to highlight these principles explicitly.)

Comment: @Wyck Thank for your kind help. Stay safe

Answer (score 0):

> Print a single integer taht denotes the minimum number of loaves that must be distributed so that every person has an even number of loaves. If it's not possible to do this, print NO.

This operations result can not be easily returned from a C# Functions. A C# Function has **one** return value, with a **single** type. And int and string are mutally exclusive return types.

Unless you are willing to go into complex and advaned machanics that do allow multiple return values (I would advise to copy the pattern used in TryParse, for bool/int return), you have to do the output inside the function with a Console.WriteLine(). That one can be given int or string. Wich also sounds more like what you are supposed to do. I would proably contain this whole code in the main function, at wich point no return makes sense.

Comment: You could return a nullable int  `int?` and either return temp or `null`. Then when we print the result, we could check to see if the result has a value, print it, or if it doesn't then print "no".  You could also follow the .NET pattern of `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` etc. which return a bool (success or fail) and use an `out` parameter for the actual value returned in the successful case.

Comment: @Wyck You can, but that has the stench of code smell. It is one of those things I do not even consider, because it feels "wrong".

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for your help. But When I use Console.WriteLine() following error messege appears ` // Solution.cs(18,16): error CS0161: Solution.fairRations(int[]): not all code paths return a value`

Comment: @DulmikaSapumal You said the funtion would return something, so it has to return something. Either a value or a Exception must come out of each possible code paths. | As I said: It is not easy to make a function that returns more then 1 value.